# How is the gradient of a radial scalar field, radial?

Tags: scalar-fields

I'm not sure if I'm mistaken: but my notes say the following.
A scalar field $f$ is radial if $f({\textbf{x}})  = \phi ( ||{\textbf{x}}||)$ for some $\phi : [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
I understand this definition, but then it goes on to say:

$$\nabla f({\textbf{x}}) = \phi ' (||{\textbf{x}}||) \frac{{\textbf{x}}}{||{\textbf{x}}||}$$
is radial. I don't see how I can pick a function $g$ say that will show that $$\nabla f({\textbf{x}}) = g(||{\textbf{x}}||).$$

Comment: The _gradient_ is not a _scalar field_. "Radial scalar field" and "Radial vector field" requires different definitions. If the book hasn't defined radial vector fields yet, then that's bad; it should have.

Comment: To add to the above, a simple definition of a radial vector field is as follows: A vector field $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})$ is radial iff $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}) = k(\mathbf{x}) \cdot \dfrac{\mathbf{x}}{\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert}$ for some scalar-valued function $k(\mathbf{x})$. Intuitively, in a radial vector field, the vector assigned to any point points directly away from the origin.

Comment: Thanks guys. Isn't the definition that $F$ is radial vector field iff $F(x) = \phi(||x||)x$ for some scalar valued function $\phi$? Or can that be transformed to your definition?

Comment: Also, about the intuition, does that have anything to do with the normal to a sphere/circle with centre at the origin? Iirc, the normal to a sphere/circle is in the form $\frac{x}{r}$ where $r$ is the radius of the sphere/circle.